# jqGrid drag and drop Receive event

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqgrid  drag and drop , i have two tables TABLE A and TABLE B, i am draging one row from  TABLE A and Droping into TABLE B,  i Want to capture new row id and data received in table, is there any receive event in jqGrid ?

Answer (score 6):

You can define `ondrop` event function (see this [Link](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#options1) ) like following

```
jQuery("#table2").jqGrid('gridDnD', {
    ondrop: function (ev, ui, getdata) {
        // var acceptId = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
        // getdata is the data from $('#table1').jqGrid('getRowData',acceptId);
        // so you have full information about dropped row
    }
});
```

inside of `ondrop`'s parameters you will find all information which you need.

Comment: Hey Oleg, awesome help once again!! Can you please view [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146892/jqgrid-drag-and-drop-row-check) whenever you get the time? I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#gbox_destinationTable tr td").droppable({
    drop : function(event, ui) {
        var draggedHtml = ui.draggable.html();
        $(this).append(draggedHtml);
        deleteFromSource(ui.draggable.parent());
    }
});

function deleteFromSource(draggedObj) {
    $('#sourceTable').jqGrid('delRowData', draggedObj.attr('id'));
}
```

You may see the complete sample for jqgrid specific implementation here : http://jsfiddle.net/pragya91/fzkqxdxm/