# Adding Custom rows in View model in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to show order particulars of a order in view model. Cliking on the order and `view` pager button passing the `orderID`. Using that `orderID`, I'm searching within another `local json array`. And I'm making a table contains search result array values and I'm adding it as new row in between rows that are already using in view model like the below image.

[image: View Model page with custom row]

*(From the above image, I color bordered row is newly created row. Other rows are by default created by jqGrid.)*

I created successfully as other rows. But It giving some trouble while clicking on the view next or previous record button in view model. See this below image,

[image: View Model with custome Row and repeated data]

*(different row's table column value append in a single row repeatedly)*

In this I navigate records `8` times through next (`#nData`) and previous (`#pData`) buttons. While doing this, leftside `<td>` of my custome row's text "Order Particulars" and the next auto generated `row's` (Total) right side `<td>`'s text repated `8` times. My each click on next or previous, it appends new row after my custom row.

Here is my code,

```
  var myData2 = <?php echo json_encode($oParticularResult) ?>;
  //Here I'm adding custom row
  var showIdRow = function ($form) {
  var $this = $(this),
  rowid = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
  var addHTML = '<tr class="FormData" id="trv_particulars"><td class="CaptionTD form-view-label ui-widget-content" 

width="30%"><b>Order Particulars</b></td>';
  addHTML += '<td class="DataTD form-view-data ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content" id="v_tot"><span>';
    addHTML += "<table border='2px'><thead><tr><td>Sl.No.</td><td>Particulars 

Name</td><td>Quantity</td><td>Amount</td></tr></thead><tbody>";
    var count = 1;
  for (i in myData2)
  {
  if(myData2[i].orderID == rowid)
  {
     addHTML += "<tr><td>"+count+"</td><td>"+myData2[i].proName+"</td><td>"+myData2[i].proQuantity+"</td><td>"+myData2

[i].proPrice+"</td></tr>";
     count++;
  }
    }
    $(addHTML).insertAfter('#trv_order_dt');
    };
    $(function () {
    var myData = <?php echo json_encode($orderResult) ?>;
  var getCellVal;
  var sel_id;
  $("#orderGrid").jqGrid({
  caption:'Order List',
  datatype:'local',
  data:myData,
  mtype:'POST',
  width:777,
  rowNum:10,
  height:100,
  sortorder:'asc',
  rowList:[10,20,30],
  rownumbers:true,
  viewrecords:true,
  gridview:false,
  autoencode:true,
  loadonce:true,
  pager:'#orderPager',
  sortname:'orderID',

  editurl:'<?php echo $this->action('editStatus'); ?>',
  colNames:['Order Number','Customer Name','Date', 'Total', 'Paid','Balance'],
  //cmTemplate:{editable:true, editrules: {required:true}},
  colModel:[
  { name:'orderID', key:true, width:30 },
  { name: 'custName', index: 'custName', width:60 },
  { name: 'order_dt', index: 'order_dt', width:60 },
  { name: 'tot', index: 'tot', width:60 },
  { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width:60 },
  { name: 'bal', index: 'bal', width:60 }],
  }).navGrid("#orderPager",
  {add:false, edit:false, view:true, del:false, search:true, refresh:true },
  {},//edit
  {jqModal: true, viewPagerButtons: true, checkOnUpdate:true, savekey: [true,13], navkeys: [false,38,40], checkOnSubmit : 

true, reloadAfterSubmit:false, closeOnEscape:true, closeAfterEdit: true,width:600, height:300}, //add
  {jqModal: true, reloadAfterSubmit:true, closeOnEscape: true,width:600, height:300}, //del
  {jqModal: true, closeAfterSearch: true, closeOnEscape: true, multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup:false, showQuery: true, 

overlay: true, recreateFilter: true,width:600, height:300 }, //search
  {jqModal: true, closeOnEscape: true, width:500,
  recreateForm: true,
  afterclickPgButtons: showIdRow,
  beforeShowForm: showIdRow
  } //view
  );
  });
```

Any one could point out where I missed ?

And I want to configure `subgrid`, using my `local data` `myData2` like the above condition. If orderID of `myData`(local json array for master grid) and `myData2` (local json array for subgrid) are same, show those `myData2` records below to parent grid row. I think all grids are it is subgrid concept already configured like the same. But I could not find any correct document or example for this. Please provide any links to configure subgrid as per the above.

**SOLUTION :**

I fixed my issue. This view model refresh each time when we clicking on next or previous button in this model. Because, I used `recreateform:true` and I'm calling the `showIdRow` on `afterclickPgButtons` and `beforeShowForm`.

I think it will not consider the my manually added row as one of the form value. Because when the form creation, the contents are loading from `myData` (data source of this grid). So, when I navigate through the next or previous button, `recreateform` is working for other rows and `afterclickPgButtons' and 'beforeShowForm` are calling `showIdRow` and appending new row below to already created row.

So, I decided to remove previously created a new row, while appending a new row. I already assigned my custom row id as `trv_particulars`. So, I used my code like this,

```
.
.
$('#tvr_Particulars').remove();  // remove previously created custome row using row ID
$('#trv_order_dt').after(addHTML);
.
.
```

Now its working fine in my scenario. But alternative and optimal solution is provided by @Oleg in the below [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23042641/2567813). Thanks to @Oleg for taking your time to create another possible solution for my issue.

Comment: I would recommend you to remove `#trv_particulars` instead of hiding to have no id duplicates. I mean that you could use `$('#tvr_Particulars').remove();` instead of `$('#tvr_Particulars').hide();`

Comment: Oh... yeah... Thanks for your suggestion @Oleg. I updated my **SOLUTION** according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find your question interesting and so I created [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/GridInRowView.htm) which demonstrates a possible implementation of such requirements. The results of the View looks like on the picture below:

[image]

Some comments to the implementation. First of all I used input data for the grid which contains detailed information needed to create "Order Details" ("Order Particulars") in the view:

```
var mydata = [
        { id: "1",  invdate: "2007-10-21", name: "test",   note: "3note",   amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00",
            subgrid: [{no: "1", amount: "750"}, {no: "2", amount: "750"}, {no: "3", amount: "600"}, {no: "4", amount: "900"}] },
        { id: "2",  invdate: "2007-10-22", name: "test2",  note: "3note2",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00",
            subgrid: [{no: "1", amount: "750"}, {no: "2", amount: "600"}, {no: "3", amount: "900"}] },
        ...
    ];
```

`subgrid` property of every item contains the information.

Next, I insert in the table of the View form the custom row with "Order Details" ("Order Particulars") after the row with information about "close" column. I use the code

```
$("#trv_closed").after('<tr class="FormData">' +
    '<td class="CaptionTD form-view-label ui-widget-content" width="40%"><b>Order Particulars</b></td>' +
    '<td class="DataTD form-view-data ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content"><div style="width:100%;height:100%">' +
    '<table id="mysubgrid"><tr><td>' +
    '</td></tr></table>' +
    '</div></td></tr>');
```

to add the row after the row `"#trv_closed"` (the id of the row will be constructed based on the name of "close" column).

Then one can rowid of the current displayed row in different ways. The first way will be to get the current selected row `$this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow")`. Another way: one can get the information from hidden column which contains `<input>` element having the rowid. One can address the `<input>` element by `id="id_g"` (`$("#id_g").val()`) or by `name="id"` (`$form.find("input[name=id]").val()`). I uses `$("#id_g").val()` in my code.

Now one can get `subgrid` property of selected row using `getLocalRow` (because we use `datatype: "local"`):

```
var localRowData = $this.jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid);
// localRowData.subgrid contains the required data
```

So the full code is

```
$("#list").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {edit: false, add: false, del: false, view: true, search: false}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {
    recreateForm: true,
    afterclickPgButtons: function (buttonName, $form, pos) {
        showDetails.call(this, $form);
    },
    beforeShowForm: showDetails,
    labelswidth: '40%'
});
```

where the function `showDetails` are defined as below

```
var showDetails = function ($form) {
    var $this = $(this),
        rowid1 = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow"),
        rowid = $("#id_g").val(), //id2 = $form.find("input[name=id]").val(),
        localRowData = $this.jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid);
    if (isClosed === "Yes") {
        $("#trv_id").show();
    }
    if ($("#mysubgrid").length === 0) {
        // if not in afterclickPgButtons for example
        $("#trv_closed").after('<tr class="FormData">' +
            '<td class="CaptionTD form-view-label ui-widget-content" width="40%"><b>Order Particulars</b></td>' +
            '<td class="DataTD form-view-data ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content"><div style="width:100%;height:100%">' +
            '<table id="mysubgrid"><tr><td>' +
            '</td></tr></table>' +
            '</div></td></tr>');
         $("#mysubgrid").jqGrid({
             datatype: "local",
             data: localRowData.subgrid,
             colNames: ["#", "Amount"],
             colModel: [
                 {name: "no", width: 40, sorttype: "integer"},
                 {name: "amount", width: 70, sorttype: "integer"}
             ],
             idPrefix: "s",
             sortname: "no",
             rowNum: 1000,
             height: "auto"
         });
    } else {
        // update $("#mysubgrid") with new data
        $("#mysubgrid").jqGrid("clearGridData")
            .jqGrid("setGridParam", {data: localRowData.subgrid})
            .trigger("reloadGrid");
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks... Let me try this and let you know the OP. Your demo link pages shows `Uncaught ReferenceError: isClosed is not defined` error. I'm eager to know why that element repeatedly added? do you have any idea?

Comment: Is there any method to `recreate` of `refresh` form while clicking on `#pData` or `#nData` ? I have a little bit issue to generate my json array like this. So only tried in this way... But, I hope, I can convert my result set like this... Let me try this...

Comment: @CJRamki: Sorry, I fixed the demo.

Comment: @CJRamki: Do you used `recreateForm: true` option like I did in the demo? it makes refreshing of View on every opting of the View form. There are no option which allows to recreate View form on click on `"#nData"` or `#pData` (see [the source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.formedit.js#L1449-L1483)). jqGrid just calls `onclickPgButtons` then fill the standard data in the View for (calls `fillData`), select next/previous row and calls `afterclickPgButtons`. So you have to implement your `afterclickPgButtons` so that it works in the scenario.

Comment: I fixed my issue. See my **SOLUTION** part in my question.

Comment: I converted my Array like yours, `rowid = $("#id_g").val(),` what is `#id_g` in this? It will return row number of grid?