# jqGrid Subgrid Local Data

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need to manually populate the subGrid when the expand + icon is clicked. I am getting:

```
[object object] [object object]
[object object] [object object]
```

in the subgrid.  My Grid Sample and Code is below. Can some one help out please? I have shared the snippet [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pdpy4Laq).

Please note: For some reason jsFiddle does not work because I am new to sharing code via jsFiddle.

Comment: your fiddle don't works

Comment: I have mentioned that my fiddle does not work. The intent was to share the code.

Comment: Sorry i have to be more specific but your snipett will never work because he don't find jquery you have uploaded, i look in console and jquery is not found, or something in the other plugin don't works with jQuery declaration

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163970/jqgrid-subgrid-with-local-data