# Drag Jqgrid one column value to another like in excel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, excel, jqgrid

How to drag the column value of jqgrid to another like dragging in excel? 
Can it be resolved? 
Below is my jgrid code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form_table').jqGrid('setCell', 2, 'column Name', '', {color: 'red'});
        jQuery("#form_table").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            mtype: "POST",
            url: '',
            colNames: ['Id', 'तालीममा सहभागीको नाम थर', 'जिल्ला', 'गा.वि.स', 'वडा नं', 'जातजाती', 'लिङ्ग', 'उमेर'],
            colModel: [
                {name: 'id', index: 'id', jsonmap: "id", hidden: true, },
                {name: 'name', index: 'name', jsonmap: "name", width: 250, editable: true},
                {name: 'district', index: 'district', jsonmap: "district", width: 100, editable: true, align: 'center', edittype: 'select', editoptions: {
                        value: {"":"",<?php
                    foreach ($districts as $district) {
                        echo "'" . $district->dis_nepali . "': '" . $district->dis_nepali . "', ";
                    }
                    ?>
                        }, defaultValue: ''}, formatter: 'select'},

                {name: 'vdc', index: 'vdc', jsonmap: "vdc", width: 100, editable: true},
                {name: 'ward_no', index: 'ward_no', jsonmap: "ward_no", width: 80, editable: true},
                {name: 'caste', index: 'caste', jsonmap: "caste", width: 100, editable: true, align: "center", edittype: 'select', editoptions: {value: {"दलीत": "दलीत","आ/जनजाती": "आ/जनजाती", "बा छ्य": "बा छ्य", "मधेसी": "मधेसी", "अन्य": "अन्य","":""}, defaultValue: ''}, formatter: "select"},
                {name: 'gender', index: 'gender', jsonmap: "gender", width: 100, editable: true, align: "center", edittype: 'select', editoptions: {value: {"महिला": "महिला", "पूरूष": "पूरूष","":""}}, formatter: "select"},
                {name: 'age_group', index: 'age_group', jsonmap: "age_group", width: 100, editable: true,}
            ],
            loadComplete: function (data) {
                var grid = jQuery("#form_table"),
                        pageSize = parseInt(grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "rowNum")),
                        emptyRows = pageSize - data.rows.length;

                if (data.rows.length == 0) {
                    for (var j = 1; j <= emptyRows; j++)
                        // Send rowId as undefined to force jqGrid to generate random rowId
                        grid.jqGrid('addRowData', undefined, {});
                }
                if (emptyRows > 0) {
                    for (var i = 1; i <= emptyRows; i++)
                        // Send rowId as undefined to force jqGrid to generate random rowId
                        grid.jqGrid('addRowData', undefined, {});
                }
            },
            jsonreader: {repeatitems: false, id: 'id', root: 'root'},
            pager: '#form_pager',
            rowNum: 10,
            toppager: true, //for pager on top
            height: "auto",
            rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
//            sortname: 'id',
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            resizable: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            loadonce: true,
            //shrinkToFit:false,
            loadtext: 'Loading...',
            cellEdit: true,
            contentType: "application/json",
            cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
            cellurl: ""
        });
        jQuery("#form_table").jqGrid('navGrid', '#form_pager', {
            cloneToTop: true,
            edit: false,
            add: false,
            del: false
        });
        jQuery("#form_table").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
            useColSpanStyle: true,
            groupHeaders: [
                {startColumnName: 'district', numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: 'ठेगाना'}
            ]
        });
}):
```

Now i want the column 2 name of row 1 to be dragged to the column 2 name upto row 15 is there any solution?
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: I have many questions to the code. I'm not sure what you mean under "dragging in excel". I suppose that you need just add the option `sortable: true` and verify that you includes jQuery UI JS file. After that one can change the order of columns by drag&drop the column headers. If you want to drag&drop the values of one row only and not the whole column, then I have to disappoint you: the feature is not exist in jqGrid.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any alternative method or any other table??

Comment: To tell the trust it's the feature of excel, which disturbs me only, because one can make drag&drop not when one really want it. It's my personal opinion. If you still have to implement the feature then you can use jQuery UI [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/). Cell editing mode, which you use, have many callbacks (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing#events)). Thus you can call `$.draggable` after editing is initialized.