# jqGrid Drag-and-Drop Receiving row highlight

Tags: jqgrid, drag-and-drop

Using jqGrid - would like to drag from Table A into an arbitrary row in Table B. Would like the rows of Table B to highlight as I hover over them during a drag. Is this possible?

Even better, can I insert into arbitrary fields in the destination row upon drop?

What I am doing is populating a row field-by-field.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know `gridDnD` method? Look at [the official jqGrid demo](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) in "New in version 3.6" and choose "Drag and Drop Rows". Other answers like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10180527/315935), [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2858459/315935) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10196208/315935) shows you some customization options and callbacks of the method.

Comment: Looked pretty hard, but having problem with the destination grid always putting drops in first row. Adding unique ids to rows / columns doesn't seem to work, either.